# How do I dynamically create an <option> in JavaScript that contains an HTML entity (— ... «)?

Tags: javascript, html-entities, html-select

I'd like to add an <option> element to a <select> element where the <option> element's text contains an HTML entity: &mdash;

In HTML, the code would look like this:

```
<select name="test" id="test">
    <option value="">&mdash; Select One &mdash;</option>
</select>
```

My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
function selectOne() {
  var e = document.getElementById('test');
  e.options[0] = new Option('&mdash; Select One &mdash;', '');
}
```

However, as you will see if you test this, the &mdash; becomes escaped. I had the same outcome when I tried:

```
e.options[o].text = '&mdash; Select One &mdash;';
```

(Observed behavior was in Internet Explorer 7 ... did not test with Firefox, Safari, etc. -- Internet Explorer 7 is the only browser I need at the moment.)

Comment: is there a reason the "-" must be escaped?

Comment: I didn't know of another way to (easily) add an mdash. If it were a simple n-dash... I'd just use the keyboard dash/minus key. I guess I should have used the example of maybe a « instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just realized I could use a Unicode JavaScript escape:

```
e.options[0] = new Option('\u2014 Select One \u2014', '');
```

Comment: Both this solution and Chetan's solution work. It just depends on which style you prefer. For me, I prefer to set the value once instead of going back and changing it afterwards like in Chetan's solution.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to escape the entity - it works like this:

```
function selectOne() {
      var e = document.getElementById('test');
      e.options[0] = new Option('— Select One —', '');
}
```

Comment: True -- but I was thinking about ANY HTML entity... like a «

Comment: This does work for any HTML entity, though it can run into encoding problems.  Your unicode escape sequences are probably the most portable solution.

Answer (score 3):

`text` property doesn't get unescaped, as it is meant to be taken literally. If you use `innerHTML`, the entities get converted to corresponding characters.

```
e.options[o].innerHTML = '&mdash; Select One &mdash;';
```