# How does one use special symbols in a choices list as names?

Tags: r, shiny

How to use Greek letters in ui.R has been discussed here before. As an example if one wants the user to input a numeric value for a parameter mu one can use:

```
numericInput("mu",HTML("&mu;"),value=0)
```

and  μ is displayed. I want to do the same thing but with the choices list in a selectInput. I have tried:

```
selectInput("param", label = "Parameter",choices=c("&alpha;" = "alpha","beta"))
```

but this just displays α. I also tried:

```
selectInput("param", label = "Parameter",choices=c(HTML("&alpha;") = "alpha","beta"))
```

and

```
selectInput("param", label = "Parameter",choices=c("HTML("&alpha;")" = "alpha","beta"))
```

but these produce errors.

Comment: You could probably replace greek letters with png graphics. You can find an app on `showmeshiny` which does something similar (the author replaces choices with images with different types of lines) 
[See in the source code a function lineOpts (line 40)](https://github.com/bchartoff/ggShinyApp/blob/master/ui.R). Pictures are in `www` folder. It maybe helps you.  [Main page of the app](http://www.showmeshiny.com/ggplot2-theme-builder/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the HTML Greek letters, but the \uXXXX version like so:

```
selectInput("param", label = "Parameter",choices=c("\u03B1" = "alpha",
                                                     "\u03B2" = "beta",
                                                     "\u03BC"="mu"))
```

Here is a table of \uXXXX for Greek letters: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/greekletters.htm

edit:
OP is correct that this won't work for Chi and many other letters for some strange reason, but if you create the named vector for choices in an earlier step it works like so:

```
choices <- c("alpha","beta","mu","chi")
names(choices) <- c("\u03B1","\u03B2","\u03BC","\u03C7")
selectInput("param","Parameters",choices=choices)
```

edit2:
Things continue to be weird with R and unicode, but I got pretty close to what you want. I can't find a working unicode in R for subscript k, but I did for subscript i so if you are willing to use a different subscript:

```
library(shiny)      
choices <- c("X^2_i")
names(choices) <- c("\u03C7\u1d62\U00B2")
runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      selectInput("param","Parameters",choices=choices)
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {

    }
  )
)
```

edit3:
I still think Unicode is the best way to go since including HTML in select options is not trivial apparently: [How do I dynamically create an <option> in JavaScript that contains an HTML entity (— ... «)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425234/javascript-how-to-dynamically-create-an-option-that-contains-an-html-entity)

I was able to get the HTML to render in the drop down, but not for the selected item.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    selectizeInput("test","test",choices=c("&chi;<sup>2</sup><sub>k</sub>"="chi_k^2"),options=list(
      labelField="name",
      create=FALSE,
      render=I(
        "{option:function(item,escape) {
          return item.name}}"
      )
    )
    )
  )
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

There may be a way to tell selectizejs to render html in the selected box, but I haven't seen it anywhere so I remain skeptical.

Comment: Carl, very strange

Comment: The idea with the png might work but seems a bit like a hack

Comment: Carl, very strange! Your code works just fine, but what I really wanted is to use as the name:  Pearson &chi<sup>2</sup>. Now on the web site you sent me there are five codes for chi: \u03C7 &#967; &chi; %u03C7 %CF%87 and none of them works! the "\u03C7" displays as <U+03C7>.      And of course I would still have the problem with the square.

Comment: Yep, pretty strange. I've edited my answer so hopefully you will be able to do what you need to.

Comment: Carl, thanks, that worked (still don't understand why the other one didn't)                                                                                                                Now for the full problem: Actually I would like to use the name &chi;<sup>2</sup><sub>k</sub> properly displayed

Comment: @WolfgangRolke it appears that there is a problem with unicode subscripts in R, so I was only able to get part of the way there with `"\u03C3\U00B2"`. Will continue looking into this

Comment: @WolfgangRolke I have a working demo if you are willing to substitute subscript k for subscript i

Comment: Actually, you can render html in the options of a selective input. Will post answer tomorrow when in front of computer

Comment: I do wonder why this great answer hasn't been accepted yet :)

Comment: UnnamedUser, the previous answer was only a partial one, and I am waiting for Carl to post how to render HTML in the options of selectInput

Comment: I was able to render html in the drop down but not for the actual selected item. Still working on a full solution. Will post eventually :)

Comment: Carl, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it! I am not sure what you mean by actual selected item, where I would like to use HTML is in what the user sees as the name.

Comment: Carl, it has been a while since your last post. Please let me know if you are going to say more, otherwise I will answer the question with what we got

Comment: I can't find a better solution. Please share yours

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the answer by Carl, and looking into the [selectizejs Readme](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md)
There is a list of fields that can be set for render.
Using "option" (the items in the list of all items) and "item" (the items that are selected) I was able to come up with the following solution that will properly render the selected input as well as those in the dropdown list:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    selectizeInput("test","test",choices=c("&chi;<sup>2</sup><sub>k</sub>"="chi_k^2"),options=list(
      labelField="name",
      create=FALSE,
      render=I(
        '
        {
            option:function(item,escape) {return String.prototype.concat("<div>", item.name, "</div>"},
            item:function(item,escape) {return String.prototype.concat("<div>", item.name, "</div>"}
        }
        '
      )
    )
    )
  )
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```